# Tree of unary operators

Tags: parsing, left-recursion, superpower

I want to parse expressions like

- a
- ++a
- a++
- ++a++
- ++a++++

The pre-increment operator has precedence over the post-increment operator.

The parsers I have are these:

```
public static readonly TokenListParser<LangToken, UnaryOperator> Increment = Token.EqualTo(LangToken.DoublePlus).Select(x => UnaryOperators.Increment);
public static readonly TokenListParser<LangToken, UnaryOperator> Decrement = Token.EqualTo(LangToken.DoubleMinus).Select(x => UnaryOperators.Decrement);

public static readonly TokenListParser<LangToken, Expression> Identifier = Token.EqualTo(LangToken.Identifier).Select(x => (Expression)new Id(x.ToStringValue()));

public static readonly TokenListParser<LangToken, Expression> A =
    from c in Parse.Ref(() => Expression)
    from op in Increment.Or(Decrement)
    select (Expression)new OpNode(op, c);

public static readonly TokenListParser<LangToken, Expression> B =
    from op in Increment.Or(Decrement)
    from c in Parse.Ref(() => Expression)
    select (Expression)new OpNode(op, c);

public static readonly TokenListParser<LangToken, Expression> Expression = A.Or(B).Or(Identifier);
```

However, when I parse a simple expression like "a++" using the `Expression` parser, the test hangs. I suppose that it's due to a recursion problem.

But what's the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: From the looks of it, you have an infinite loop that's occurring in the `Expression` parser.  `Expression` calls `A` which calls `Expression` which calls `A`, and so on.  Can you post the definitions for `LangToken`, `UnaryOperator`, `UnaryOperators`, `OpNode`, and `Id` so I could get a working sample up and running locally?